# Splitting a DataFrame based on a condition

Tags: python, dataframe

```
   df = {'Source': ['-23456','-23456','3456','','56789','-12456','-13245','','45678','12346','','-23456','-23456','-234556','124566','098745','-67890'],
      'number_mp': [369452,369452,369452,369452,369452,369452,369452,369452,369452,369452,369452,369452,369452,369452,369452,369452,369452],
      'time_Utc': ["2014-9-12","2014-9-12","2014-9-12" ,"2017-5-14","2017-5-14","2017-5-14","2016-10-26" ,"2016-10-26" ,"2016-10-26" ,"2016-11-3" ,"2016-11-3" ,"2016-8-10" ,"2016-8-10","2016-8-10","2014-9-12","2014-9-12","2014-9-12"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I have a Dataframe and I want to divide it into sub Dataframes with the condition that each one is grouped with three different values of "time_Utc" ordered from smallest to largest.

I used the following but values with equal dates are grouped and I don't know how to put the condition that they are with different dates.

```
res = []
for _ in range(len(df)):
    tabla = df.sample(n=3)
    res.append(tabla)
print(res)
```

Could someone help me please.

Comment: _" divide it into sub Dataframes"_: What do you exactly mean by that: (1) Do you want a couple of _random_ samples (if so, how much) or do you want all possible sub dataframes that meat your requirements? (2) Can the sub dataframes _overlap_, i.e. different sub dataframes can have common rows?

Comment: I want all possible sub dataframes that meat your requirements @Timus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure I understand your goal, but here's a suggestion:

First group the indices in blocks, each block containing the indices that belong to the same date, and the blocks ordered by date:

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import combinations, product

def key(group): return datetime.strptime(group[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
idx_blocks = [sdf.index for _, sdf in sorted(df.groupby("time_Utc"), key=key)]
```

Result (`idx_blocks`):

```
[Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 14, 15, 16], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([11, 12, 13], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([6, 7, 8], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([9, 10], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([3, 4, 5], dtype='int64')]
```

Then use [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to select all combinations of 3 index blocks (they remain sorted), use [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to pick all possible index-triples from them, and collect the corresponding sub-dataframes:

```
samples = [
    df.loc[idx, :]
    for blocks in combinations(idx_blocks, 3)
    for idx in product(*blocks)
]
```

You'll get a list of sample-dataframes like:

```
    Source  number_mp    time_Utc
0   -23456     369452   2014-9-12
11  -23456     369452   2016-8-10
6   -13245     369452  2016-10-26

    Source  number_mp    time_Utc
0   -23456     369452   2014-9-12
11  -23456     369452   2016-8-10
7              369452  2016-10-26

...

   Source  number_mp    time_Utc
8   45678     369452  2016-10-26
10            369452   2016-11-3
4   56789     369452   2017-5-14

    Source  number_mp    time_Utc
8    45678     369452  2016-10-26
10             369452   2016-11-3
5   -12456     369452   2017-5-14
```

But be aware that the amount of these samples can get out of hand pretty quickly. The small sample dataframe you've provided already leads to 351 samples.